# Is it safe to mix Hyundai OEM coolant (green color) with Prestone Cor-guard 50/50 coolant (neon yellow)?

Tags: coolant, hyundai

My 2011 Hyundai Santa Fe came with the Hyundai OEM green coolant. I bought a [Prestone](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81x4BTqZfQL._SL1500_.jpg) coolant (neon yellow color) because the coolant in the expansion tank is low. Is it safe to mix those two coolants? (Prestone bottle says it's guaranteed for all vehicles (American/Asian/European)) Thank you!

Comment: Does it say it's guaranteed if you only use the same coolant, or does it say it's guaranteed even when mixed? Generally, the colors are there to indicate the type of the coolant, and mixing colors is not recommended. Also, what does your car's manual say about the type of the coolant? What year Santa Fe do you have? I would follow the car manufacturer's recommendation for the coolant type. E.g. Toyota requires ethylene glycol based nonsilicate, non-amine, non-nitrite, non-borate coolant with long-life hybrid organic acid technology, with is pink.

Comment: Coolant is cheap, just buy the OEM stuff from the Hyundai dealer.

Comment: @juhist it says "works with any color antifreeze"

Answer (score -1):

If it's only slightly low (say, less than a half liter, conservatively), I'd just add some distilled water and call it good. You don't want to do this repeatedly between coolant flushes because you'll dilute the mixture too much. However, if you're routinely having to add coolant you have bigger problems.